# Where is histreedit in Zsh?

Tags: zsh

What is the Bash `shopt -s histreedit` equivalent in Zsh ?

From Bash reference manual:

```
histreedit

    If set, and Readline is being used, a user is given the opportunity to re-edit a failed history substitution.
```

Comment: Questions about interactive use as opposed to scripting are better suited to [UNIX.se].